# Invalid values in the custom Organization policy in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, organization

I would like to modify the existing policies - Restrict allowed Google Cloud APIs and services. Based on the project (New project), I would like to allow only limited APIs and services. Just for explore, I am trying the same.I was trying to allow some of the APIs and services. Ex: Compute Engine

> compute.googleapis.com.

I am getting the "one or more rules contain invalid values". Any help on the same?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any mention of **“ : ”** results in input being [invalidated](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/creating-managing-policies#list_constraints).  The usage of the prefix  **“api : "** is invalid because it is not supported by the policy- [Restrict allowed Google Cloud APIs and services.](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)  The workaround to fix this is adding an **"is:"** prefix which is supported by the policy, because the validator  now always expects the first colon is a separator between prefix (Supported prefixes for specific constraints- "is:", "in:", "under:") and value.

**EDIT :**

I have reproduced the issue and everything worked as expected. Can you try again by changing the "**policy value**" field exactly with the string **`is:compute.googleapis.com`** without mistyping any spaces in between. Refer to the screenshots for reference.

[screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPMXf.png)

[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6c03W.png)

Comment: It's very strange. Even I tried the prefix "is" and in & under. But I am getting the same error.